# Creating multiple local notifications at once fails

Tags: ios, notifications, swift2, localnotification

I'm working with local notification on iOS, but I'm having some problems when iOS tries to create the notifications. Some of them are created and some won't.

After reviewing my code a lot, I found that it was failing at the point where it was creating the local notification.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

The only reason I could think of was that creating the notifications inside a loop, around 50-60 notifications, was too much for iOS to process. I'm doing it this way because all the notifications have a different time and different day, and belong to different things.

This is my block to create the local notifications:

```
    let createdUid = self.generateNotificationUUID()

    // create a corresponding local notification
    let notification = UILocalNotification()

    /* Time and timezone settings */
    notification.fireDate = self.buildTime()
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

    /* Information settings */
    notification.alertBody = "Sector \(notificationData["sector"]!): located at \(notificationData["name"]!) closes in 15 min."
    notification.alertAction = "Open"

    /* Badge settings */
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
    notification.soundName = "ring.caf"
    notification.userInfo = ["UUID": createdUid, ]

    /* Schedule the notification */       
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

And all this code is inside a loop. The same loop before calling the notification creation, dynamically builds the notificationData array.

The notification data array contains the sector, the name, and the time and day.

Time and day is used to calculate the notification fire date.
Sector and Name are used for the alert body.
And all the four values are used to generate the UID (UUID).

If I put a print and remove the UIApplication.sharedApplication()... all the data looks good and what it needs to be.

I've tried, to solve the problem, using

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {...}

and

dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {...}

But with async I received the same result that I had without it, and using sync my screen freezes.

I kind of lost with this, I'm sure that my issues are because iOS doesn't process in time all the notification creation, but I dunno how to fix it.

I hope someone can help me, I'm using **XCode 7.3.1** and **Swift 2.2**

Comment: You should try Xcode 8 beta or Xcode 7.3 to see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/

> An app can have only a limited number of scheduled notifications; the
>   system keeps the soonest-firing 64 notifications (with automatically
>   rescheduled notifications counting as a single notification) and
>   discards the rest.

Comment: This is the problem. I'll have to look for a different approach. Thanks.